# How can I hide body::after upon hover over body (with transitions)?

Tags: css

I'm trying to display a message when the page loads, and that works okay, but let's say I want the message to disappear after a few seconds after hovering over the body? Here is my code, which loads the message but doesn't hide it on hover:

```
body::after {
  content: "Hello!" !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  font-size: 2.1em !important;
  color: black !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: -5px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  display: visible !important;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, display 2s ease-in-out !important;
}

body:hover ~ body::after {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  display: none !important;
}
```

Please don't offer alternatives using other coding languages; I need to use only CSS. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `body:hover ~ body::after`, just use `body:hover::after` instead.

```css
body::after {
  content: "Hello!" !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  font-size: 2.1em !important;
  color: black !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  background: #FFF !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: -5px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  display: visible !important;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, display 2s ease-in-out !important;
}

body:hover::after {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  I'm the body!
</body>
```